# direct access and update section of file on hard disk

Tags: io, operating-system, hard-drive

I wonder if I can do the following and how:
I have an extremely large file in a fixed width format stored in a hard disk with *NIX system. I want to know if one can do update on a portion of the big file without read in and write out the entire file in the memory. For example of the following file, I want to go to a specific location "5" on the hard disk and replace only the content EE to ZZ without rewrite the entire file.

1    AA
   2    BB
   3    CC
   4    DD
   5    EE ->ZZ
   6    FF
   7    GG
   8    HH
   9    II
   ..   ..

Regardless of programming language, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy to do, as long as you **replace** contents with new contents - you can't add or remove anything.  Think of the file contents as a long strip of tape stuck to a table.  You can cut out a piece of tape and replace it with another piece **of the exact same length** without disturbing the rest of the tape.  But if you want to replace the piece you cut out with a shorter or longer piece, you have to pull up lots of tape and stick it back down somewhere else to keep a continuous strip of tape.

Comment: Thanks for answering, contents will be replaced by another piece of exact same length, could you please elaborate on how it is done (which language to use, what functions, procedures) or point to some tutorials?